# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable given when using 'sum()' on a list

Tags: python, list, sum, nonetype

I am getting

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

when I try to find the sum of a list.

Where the problem occurs:

```
if(sum(self._candidates) + self._allCandidates[self._depth]._weight > 20):
    self._left = Node(self._candidates, self._depth + 1, self._allCandidates)
else:
    self._left = Node(self._candidates.append(self._allCandidates[self._depth]), self._depth + 1, self._allCandidates)
```

Node definition:

```
def __init__(self, candidates = [], depth = -1, allCandidates = []):
        self._candidates = candidates
        self._depth = depth
        self._allCandidates = allCandidates
```

Thanks for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
Node(self._candidates.append(self._allCandidates[self._depth])
```

The return value from `.append` is `None`, hence the error.

Comment: Also, you're going to get yourself in big trouble with that `candidates=[]` default argument. That is evaluated at function definition time, so all instances of the class will share the same list (unless another list is passed in). Advise copying the list: `self._candidates = candidates[:]`